# React state setter function not changing the state

Tags: javascript, react-state

I am working on a history component in my React project. I have the `history` state and a setter function `setHistory()` . I have two functions for handling clicks: `handleClick()` and `removeHistoryItem()`, which are called with different buttons. In both of them, I am changing the state with the `setHistory()` function, but it doesn't work in the `handleClick()` one.

```
const removeHistoryItem = () => {
    const newHistory = history.filter(item => item.id != id)
    setHistory(newHistory)
}
    
 const handleClick = () => {
    let newHistory = history
    let [selectedGame] = history.filter(item => item.id == id)
    const index = history.indexOf(selectedGame)
    
    selectedGame.isFavorite = !selectedGame.isFavorite
    newHistory.splice(index, 1, selectedGame)
    localStorage.setItem('history', JSON.stringify(newHistory))
    setHistory(newHistory)
}
```

The functions are next to each other so there shouldn't be a problem with the scope. Both functions are executing the other operations well (tested with `console.log()`, the localStorage is changed just fine, the splice and filter functions are working also). Even the value I am passing to the `setHistory()` function is correct, just the state is not changed. It's like the `setHistory()` function is not even called. I am not getting any errors, what could the problem be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is due to Reference equality, both `newHistory` and `history` in your handleClick function are referencing same array in "memory", which you mutate with `splice`, but it is still the same object, react will not detect the change and will not fire the rerender, just because oldValue (history) === newValue (newHistory).

So you need to "recreate" the array in this case. For `removeHistoryItem` all is ok due to `.filter` returns the new array already, so new reference, new object.

```
setHistory([...newHistory]);
```